# Spring Security java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'ROLE_ADMIN'

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-3, spring-4

I'm working with the book "**Amuthan G - Spring MVC Beginner's Guide**". Currently I'm trying to implement security using the next `security-context.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">
    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/products/add" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
                             default-target-url="/products/add"
                             authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"/>
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="Admin" password="Admin123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

Security related configuration in the `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/security-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But this example end up with `IllegalArgumentException` while opening the secured path:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'ROLE_ADMIN'
    org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:30)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:206)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:106)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'ROLE_ADMIN' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot' - maybe not public?
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
    org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:26)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:206)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:106)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
```

It looks like this issue is related to obsolete security configuration but I failed to find something in migration guide from Spring 3 to Spring 4. Are there any soluions or I should just implement it another way?

Comment: Sorry, that was off-topic question. It seems solution works well. But the whole instance of the code is quite obsolete and I unfortunately get many problems with it. Anyway thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello. I'm working on the same book as you did. Yesterday I was getting the same error as you did. But suddenly today I got an HTTP 404 because of the items added in `web.xml` for spring security. Did you get that error ?  So because of that 404 I can't correct the 500 based on your answer

Comment: This book is too old. Do not use it. It is much more outdated than I thought year ago. Spring changed a lot since this book was printed. Take a look at books/tutorials that are no older than late 2016.

Answer (score 11):

The main problem was in this line:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/products/add" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

It should be replaced with the next line:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/products/add" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```