# HTTP 404 : conflict between spring security url filter and dispatcher servlet url mapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have 2 problems here :

- 1st : I get a HTTP 404. I think there is a conflict between spring security filter url mapping and the dispatcher servlet mapping. I'm saying that because when I remove the spring security configuration from my `web.xml`, the request mapping process works fine.
- 2nd : I get the "notorious" HTTP 500 Failed to evaluate expression 'ROLE_ADMIN'

Now how is it possible for me to have problem 2 if I get a 404 in the first place ? I have no idea about that. Yesterday everything was working fine for problem 1 so I was getting the HTTP 500. Today, I can;t get passed the HTTP 404. At least I have identified the culprit in my config.

Please help me solve problem 1 <- this is the main gal of this question (and if you're kind problem 2 also)... Below are my xml configuration files.

**Web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- For front controller i.e. dispatcher servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- For Spring security --> 
    <!-- When I remove all items below, my app works fine -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**DispatcherServlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- To enable spring annotations @RequestMapping, @Controller, @Repository, etc... -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- To enable @MatrixVariable -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>

    <!-- To set the package where dispatcher servlet looks for controllers
    Some other scanning for other purpose may also occur in that package
    For instance for @Autowired to look for interfaces-->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.packt.webstore" />

    <!-- Sets where ViewResolver looks for views -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- For static resources. Example : CSS, JS, etc... -->    
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/ressources/theme1/" />

    <!-- For externalizing messages -->
    <bean id= "messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**security-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/products/add" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
                             default-target-url="/products/add"
                             authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"/>
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="Admin" 
                               password="Admin123" 
                               authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

As you can see in the `security-cntext.xml` config, I have tried to solve problem 2 by adding `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719769/spring-security-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-evaluate-expressio)

Comment: try to replace `ROLE_ADMIN` with `ADMIN`. It should add prefix `ROLE_` automatically as far as I remember

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich But what about the HTTP 404 ? I can't get to the part where changing `ROLE_ADMIN` to `ADMIN` because of the HTTP 404

Comment: are you sure it is the right location: `location="/ressources/theme1/"`? I mean two `ss` in `ressources`

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich  Yes. Don't worry about static resources. Everything works fne. I made some typos but basically, `/src/main/webapp/ressources/theme1` is my base directory for static ressources

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich  Problem solved. See the answer below. Thanks for your help mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe versions? check your `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute in the two files. they differ. You can remove the versions.

From: `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd`

To: `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd`

etc.. Maybe that will do it.

Comment: For all `xsi` showing version or just for `MVC`'s ones ?

Comment: For all of them. I had a problem related to the versions. removed them and it worked

Comment: Yes !!!! Removing versions everywhere except `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"` of `<web-app version="3.0"` solved the issue. Do you know why that blocked me ? Now I have another issue like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004035/could-not-verify-the-provided-csrf-token-because-your-session-was-not-found-in-s) but this is something else.  Thank you very much Jack. ...ps : vote my question up ;-)

Comment: @Bloomberg58 sure you need to keep the servlet version. for the rest, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20900801/3959856